# How to run DocFx plugins & post processors under docfx.console?

Tags: docfx

I have successfully integrated DocFx with a Visual Studio project, using docfx.console, as described [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html#3-use-docfx-integrated-with-visual-studio) and [here](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/05/generating-documentation-with-docfx-as.html).

Under this setup, the building of the project triggers DocFx to process the docfx.json and markdown files found under the project. I do not directly execute docfx.exe. This works both when building the project manually in Visual Studio, and when building on a build server.

I am using the default DocFx template (there is no extracted template in my project) and docfx.console 2.48.1 (the latest as of now).

I am now trying to integrate a custom DocFx plugin & post processor. I have taken two samples from Github ([RtfDocumentProcessor](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/howto_build_your_own_type_of_documentation_with_custom_plug-in.html) & [DocFx.Plugin.LastModified](https://github.com/Still34/DocFx.Plugin.LastModified)) and created a new .NET Framework 4.7.2 class library, which builds OK.

The problem is how to modify the docfx.json to tell DocFx to use the plugin & post processor. The above articles assume docfx.exe is run directly, and also that there is a "template" folder, for example:

> 1. Build our project.
> 2. Copy the output dll files to:
>
>    - Global: the folder with name Plugins under DocFX.exe
>    - Non-global: the folder with name Plugins under a template folder. Then run DocFX build command with parameter -t {template}.

I have tried putting my class library DLL in many different folders, and tried modifying the "template" and "postProcessors" settings in docfx.json, but in every case the build fails with a message like this (this is complaining about the DocFx.Plugin.LastModified post processor, which I tried running by setting: "postProcessors": [ "ExtractSearchIndex", "LastModifiedPostProcessor" ]):

> Warning:[BuildCommand]Can't import: LastModifiedPostProcessor,
>   System.Composition.Hosting.CompositionFailedException: No export was
>   found for the contract 'IPostProcessor "LastModifiedPostProcessor"'.

Does anyone have instructions on how to get this to work with docfx.console?